# Регистрация Юридических лиц в 1C битрикс

Tags: php, битрикс

Здравствуйте. Проблема такая. Делаю магазин на 1С битрикс и никак не могу найти выбор между регистрацией физического лица и юридического. Нужно что бы пользователь регистрировался с полями (КПП, ИНН и т.д). И эти поля автоматом подставлялись при заказе. Как это реализовать? Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 2):

Для этого нужно:

- добавить дополнительные свойства в профиль пользователя;
- кастомизировать саму форму регистрации (добавлять туда созданные поля и возможность переключения типа пользователя);
- кастомизировать личный кабинет пользователя для самостоятельного изменения данных;
- кастомизировать компонент оформления заказа, для подстановки значений из профиля.

Сделать это относительно не сложно, но объём работ довольно большой.

По умолчанию такого функционала в битриксе, увы, нет. Можно создать идею на сайте [идей для битрикса](https://idea.1c-bitrix.ru/).

Comment: Или поискать в маркетплейсе. Есть подобные решения, например **Сотбит: Расширенная регистрация и авторизация**.